# Adding information to excel sheet using matlab without xlswrite

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to add information to the end of an excel sheet using MATLAB R2019. However, MATLAB doesn't support `xlswrite` anymore

```
 [mainSize,~] = size(mainraw);
 xlswrite('test.xlsx',A,1,int2str(mainSize+1));
```

how can I make it work on MATLAB R2019?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) has been deprecated. As mentioned in the `xlswrite` [docmentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) the alternatives are [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html), [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html), and [`writecell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writecell.html).

For your case try to use [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) to append data to the contents of `Sheet1`; as in:

```
writematrix(A,'test.xlsx','Sheet','Sheet1','Range','A1', ...
           'WriteMode','append');
```